# Why is a non-static data member reference not a variable?

Tags: c++, variables, c++11, standards, definition

The definition of a *variable* in C++11 is as follows (§3/6):

> A *variable* is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object. The variable’s name denotes the reference or object.

So a non-static data member reference is not a variable. Why is this distinction necessary? What's the rationale here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way I can declare a variable in C++:

```
int scientist = 7;
```

After this declaration (and definition, in this case), I can use `scientist` to read and set its value, take its address, etc. Here's another kind of declaration:-

```
class Cloud {
    public:
    static int cumulonimbus = -1;
};
```

This one is a bit more complicated, because I have to refer to the new variable as `Cloud::cumulonimbus`, but I can still read and set its value, so it's still obviously a variable. Here's a yet different kind of declaration:-

```
class Chamber {
    public:
    int pot;
};
```

But after this declaration, there isn't a variable called `pot`, or `Chamber::pot`. In fact there's no new variable at all. I've declared a new class, and *when I later declare an instance of that class* it will have a member called `pot`, but right now, nothing is called that.

A non-static data member of class doesn't create a new variable itself, it just helps you to define the properties of the class. If it did create a new variable, you'd be able to write code like this:

```
class Chamber {
    public:
    int pot;
};

void f(bool b) {
    if (b)
        Chamber::pot = 2;
}
```

What would that even mean? Would it find every instance of `Chamber` and set all their `pot`s to 2? It's a nonsense.

A quick footnote: the language of the standard here is talking specifically about references, but to make the examples easier, I've been using non-references. I hope you can see this doesn't change the principle of it.

Comment: This makes sense, but then why does it only restrict references and not all objects in general?

Comment: Because the definition of an *object* already has that restriction. The *variable* definition is only creating a new thing that's either a reference or an object.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but according to the definition of *variable*, the declaration of member `pot` in your example introduces a variable. Where does the standard say that non-static data member declarations of objects are not variables?

Comment: The declaration of `pot` doesn't introduce a variable for the simple reason that it doesn't introduce an object. It is a *member-declaration*, not a *declaration*, so it declares a member of the class, rather than introducing a new object. That's the whole point of the question: the special language for references is to mirror this property that objects have anyway.

Comment: @sftrabbit the standard language was simply defective. the committee this week decided that and will fix it so that it makes also non-reference non-static data members be not variables.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub Do you have a reference for that? That's pretty interesting.

Comment: @sftrabbit you wanna look at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1529

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb It actually looks like they're not changing the definition of variable, but are changing the phrasing "variable or data member" to more clearly show that they mean "variable or non-static data member reference". Even with this change, non-static non-reference data members are still considered variables.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Ah, that issue was brought up in July. Did they decide this week that they would change the definition of variable as a fix for this issue?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I understand what you mean. The distinction is that there *will be* a member subobject called `pot` when an instance of `Chamber` is declared: but it's that later declaration that introduces the new objects. The member declaration inside the definition of `Chamber` doesn't *itself* introduce a new object, it just sets things up for later declarations to introduce new member sub-objects.

Comment: @dan you are talking about when memory is reserved/the object a declaration introduces a name for is created. sure that is later, at runtime. that is the case also for local object variables.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about runtime at all. I'm talking about which declaration introduces the object. A program consisting only of `class Chamber { float pot }; int main(int,char**) { return 0; }` has no objects of type `float`; whereas a program `class Chamber { float pot }; int main(int,char**) { Chamber c; return 0; }` has one. Clearly, it's the declaration of `c` which introduces an instance of `Chamber` and a member subobject of type `float`. A *member-declaration* is not a *declaration*.

Comment: this is just the same as with local automatic variables. there will be no object at runtime either if you dont call the surrounding function, and there may be multiple objects if you call it recursively. what is the difference of them to nonstatic datamembers? if you want, you can call local automatic variables "function nonstatic datamembers" and then the analogy is obvious. and for the class members you dont even need an object to refer to them at compile time. taking your example, you can say `sizeof(Chamber::pot * 3)`. try that with a local automatic without a function call.

Comment: also i fail to understand the point of you saying that a *member-declaration* is not a *declaration* in the syntax (despite the fact that some *member-declarations* syntactically contain *declaration*). the standard has the concept of a declaration, which unfortunately is both the name of a grammar rule and the name of the semantic process of introducing a name into the program.

Comment: @JosephMansfield So both "non-static, reference and non-reference data members" are not variables then? I am at my wits' end trying to understand this sentence "_A variable is introduced by the **declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object**..._", specially the part in bold.