# Are non-static non-reference data member declarations variables?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I want to reshoot a question based on the answer and appending discussion of:
[Why is a non static data member reference not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12987466/4884487):

> A non-static data member of class doesn't create a new variable itself, it just helps you to define the properties of the class. If it did create a new variable, you'd be able to write code like this:

```
class Chamber {
public:
    int pot;
};

void f(bool b) {
    if (b)
    Chamber::pot = 2;
}
```

> What would that even mean? Would it find every instance of Chamber and set all their pots to 2? It's a nonsense.

---

However, in the current [n4296 c++17 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) a variable is still definened as (`§3.6`):

> A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an
>   object. The variable’s name, if any, denotes the reference or object.

The argumentation in the *accepted* answer seems logical to me but it is, based on my understanding of the variable-definition above, conflicting with the standard.

**Question** Are non-static non-reference data member declarations variables, and if yes, why are they considered to be so since I cannot use them in an intuitive fashion ( as e.g. `Chamber::pot` from the example in the answer )  ?

Comment: A declaration of a non-static data member doesn't declare an object, and therefore doesn't introduce a variable.

Comment: It does, it is a member subobject

Comment: Yes they are *variables*, but without an instance of the class they don't really exist.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude They can't be variables. If a member declaration is a variable declaration, there must also be exactly one definition (**[basic.def.odr]/4**). Unless you want to argue that it's a weird kind of variable that is never *odr-used* (but then in what sense it is an object?)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't contribute to this discussion. I'm busy trying to count all the angels dancing on the head of this pin, right here...

Comment: This is my position: a member declaration doesn't declare an object. An instance of a class object does have subobjects, which can be referred to by a member-access expression that involves a name of a data member - but that doesn't mean that a data member declaration itself declares an object or introduces a variable.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Would dancing angels  constitute *odr-use* of the member subobject `head` of the object `pin`?

Comment: The answer is in the last citation of the standard, there is no debate, this just a convention. So for rephrasing the standard, a non static data member is a variable if it is not a reference.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Non-static member declarations *are* definitions.

Comment: @Oliv, no, you've misunderstood the quote from the standard.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I have not great pretention  with english syntax, especialy when it involves ellipsis, I read this sentence this way: "A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non static datat member or ... of an object" Then I replace the ellipsys by "A variable is introduced by the declaration". Honnestly I can you rephrase me this sentence? I can't find the correct rephrasing.

Comment: @Oliv, A variable is introduced either by the declaration of a reference that isn't a non-static data member, or by the declaration of an object. The question is about non-static non-reference data members. A non-static non-reference data member declaration does not declare a reference (because it's a non-reference), and it does not declare an object (see my answer below). So it doesn't introduce a variable.

Comment: @Barry *"Non-static member declarations are definitions."* I never argued otherwise. My point was, if they were definitions of objects, or of variables, then a routine practice of defining a class in multiple translation units (usually via putting it in a header) would constitute an ODR violation (which requires there to be exactly one definition of a variable in a program).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as Igor Tandetnik pointed out in the comments, non-static data member declarations are never variables, because they are never objects. They are declarations that give the member an object type, but there are no objects until an instance of the class is created.

Quoting [Richard Smith](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/reQ0ZVFTu_E/5P1gRvf2DgAJ):

> I suppose the problem is in the ambiguity of what a "declaration of a reference" is. I believe the intent here is that a "declaration of a reference" is a declaration that declares a particular name to be of reference type (which a non-static data member declaration of reference type does), not necessarily a declaration that causes the lifetime of a particular reference to begin. Conversely, a "declaration of an object" is intended to be interpreted as a declaration that declares a particular name to name a specific object (which a non-static data member declaration does not).
>
> That is:
>
> ```
>   struct A {
>     int &a;
>     int b;
>   };
> ```
>
> 'a' is a declaration of a reference, and so we need another condition to restrict it from being a variable. 'b' is /not/ a declaration of an object, so we don't need to say anything further.
>
> Suggestions on how to reword this to make it clearer would be welcome :)

This was followed up as https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/1280, some inconsistencies were found. With some luck, this will be seen as a good opportunity to clear up the standard at the same time.

Comment: What does [\[intro.object\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#2) mean if member variables aren't objects?

Comment: @Barry In the example here, given `A a { /* ... */ };`, [intro.object] does apply to `a.b`, it just doesn't apply to `A::b`.

Comment: I think my head exploded at Johannes' followup about how something is the declaration of an object but not an object declaration. I have no idea what any of this means anymore.

Comment: @Barry Indeed, it's very confusing. If I'm reading correctly: declarations can be split into two categories, object declarations and function declarations. Declarations of references are simply declarations where the type given is a reference type. Declarations of references are always object declarations. Declarations of objects, on the other hand, are declarations that by themselves cause an object to be created, which non-static data members do not.

Comment: Barry, the declaration of a non-static data member is not a subobject, because there's no object at that point. Once you create an object of the class type _then_ you have a subobject for the data member. But not at the point of declaring a non-static data member.

Comment: @JonathanWakely So the distinction is of "other than a non-static data member" merely exists because if one said "reference or object" that would erroneously include reference non-static data members?

Comment: @Barry, right. Non-static data member declarations never introduce variables. Declaring an object introduces a variable, and declaring a reference (e.g as a global, or local, or a parameter, but not as a non-static data member) introduces a variable.

Comment: "An object is created by a definition,..." eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#1 A decleration of a non-static data member is a definition. eel.is/c++draft/basic.def#2.20 A non-static member is a subobject eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#note-2 A subobject is an object eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#intro.object-2 There must be a standard defect somewhere, because this contradicts any sensible intuition about how members of objects work.

Answer (score 2):

> The argumentation in the accepted answer seems logical to me but it is, based on my understanding of the variable-definition above, conflicting with the standard.

There is no conflict with the standard, you've misunderstood the text you quote from §3.6.

A non-static data member is not an object, so it's not a variable either.

An object occupies a region of storage for the duration of its lifetime (see [intro.object]). A non-static data member declaration does not begin the lifetime of some thing that occupies a region of storage. So it doesn't create an object.

When you construct an object of the class' type there will be a sub-object corresponding to the data member, but that subobject is created when the enclosing object is created, and only exists for the object's lifetime. It is not created by the declaration of the data member in the class.

i.e. a subobject for the data member is created when the class object that contains it is created, not when the data member is declared.

So if it's not an object, then it's not a variable.

> **Question** Are non-static non-reference data member declarations variables,

No.

Comment: `A non-static data member declaration does not begin the lifetime of some thing that occupies a region of storage.` I don't think the declaration must begin the lifetime of something or occupies a region for that entity. Consider this declaration `extern int value;`, Isn't the `value` not an object? Instead, I think the standard should explicitly define the concept of what is the declaration of an object.

Comment: "An object is created by a definition,..." https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#1
A decleration of a non-static data member is a definition. https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def#2.20
A non-static member is a subobject https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#note-2
A subobject is an object https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#intro.object-2
There must be a standard defect somewhere, because this contradicts any sensible intuition about how members of objects work, as it would mean each instance's member would be the same pre-created object and I believe your answer captures the real intent.