# What exactly is a "declaration of an object" according to the standard

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This question is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053409/are-non-static-non-reference-data-member-declarations-variables) and [this issue](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/1280)

[The definition of *variable*](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#6) relies on the term *declaration of an object*, but this is not clearly defined anywhere. Would it be synonymous with [*object declaration*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#10.sentence-2) (and therefore only apply to a declaration introduced with a *simple-declaration*) and therefore make function parameter declaration not be *variables*, or is it something else?

Comment: On what basis do you decide that object declaration is a kind of simple-declaration?

Comment: @n.m. Look at the definition linked in the question, it's referring to the decl-specifier-seq of an simple declaration.

Comment: decl-specifier-seq is also a part of a parameter-declaration, not only of a simple-declaration. Why do you think it refers to one and not to the other?

Comment: @n.m. because it's saying "If *the* decl-specifier-seq", which is specifically referring to the decl-specifier-seq of a simple-declaration (as a previous paragraph was talking about simple-declarations) see the issue linked, Jens says this too.

Comment: There is a problem with this interpretation. The previous paragraph says, for example: *The defining-type-specifiers in the decl-specifier-seq and the recursive declarator structure of the init-declarator describe a type*. Does this also apply only to simple-declarations? If so, what do defining-type-specifiers in a parameter declaration do?

Comment: @n.m. They do, they type of a function parameter is described in http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#5.sentence-2

Answer (score 4):

The paragraph right before it defines *declaration* (*[basic.5]*) :

> Every name that denotes an entity is introduced by a *declaration*.

ie. a *declaration* is something that introduces a *name* that denotes an *entity*.

A *declaration of an object* thus introduces a *name* that denotes an *object*.

Eg. :

```
int a; // a declaration of an object with name "a" -> a variable
```

The definition of *parameter* can be found in *[defns.parameter]* :

> object or reference declared as part of a function declaration or definition or in the catch clause of an exception handler that acquires a value on entry to the function or handler

which matches the definition for *variable* (*[basic.6]*) :

> A *variable* is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object.

Eg.

```
void foo(int a); // the parameter is a declaration of an object with name "a" -> a variable
```

Comment: I think this answer would benefit from a few examples, even though the OP just asked for the standard

Comment: @AnonymousAnonymous : were those the kind of examples you had in mind ?

Comment: Yes. Maybe you could add something like `struct obj;` too - because it seems like declarations (w/o definitions) of structs and classes are less known

Comment: Ok, so looking at [class.mem] it's specified that member-declarations declare members, and does not specify that they declare objects (which makes sense for NSDMs) however for static data members, it is not specified that they declare objects, so purely going off the wording,that would make them not be variables, right (they are variables though, as that is the intent)

Comment: @KrystianS : the definition of *variable* explicitly excludes non-static data member references. Furthermore, regular (non-reference) non-static data member declarations also do not introduce a variable, since it's not an object (it's just declaring the data members of a class type). Static data members are a different matter. I'm not sure if the standard mentions explicitly whether a static data member declaration is a declaration of an object and thus introduces a variable, but reading *[class.static.data]* and the definition of *variable*, it seems clear that that's the intent.