# are c++ members not a variable but just a name of a data type?

Tags: c++, struct, language-lawyer

Does the member (declared as a variable) of a struct refer just to the data type of a variable?

for ex:

```
struct person{

 int age;
 float weight;
 string city;

}mike;
mike.age=43;
mike.weight=130.3;
mike.city="London";
```

is age refered to the Integer part of the variable mike? and it's just a label to refere to the data type  (because is declared as a variable in the struct)?

Comment: This is a straightforward question, but the answer is quite complicated.  You may want `language-lawyer` tag if you want chapter-and-verse from the standard.

Comment: The identifier `age` refers to a field or member of the `struct`.  The `int` indicates that `age` is a signed integer.  The `int` also has a size with it.  The compiler will take the type information into consideration when layout the variables (fields) within the structure.

Comment: The name of the member refers to a "slot" within a structure.  Structures can have more than one field (member) of the same type.  Thus the member name helps identify which integer within the structure.

Comment: Short answer: no. And if you're asking a language-lawyer question, please put more effort into grammar, spelling and punctuation.

Comment: I recommend you change your perspective.  The name `age` refers to a member variable or field within the structure.  The `int` happens to be the data type of the member variable; similar to a variable outside of a structure.  Focus more on the name of the field or variable within the structure, less on the type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are non-static non-reference data member declarations variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053409/are-non-static-non-reference-data-member-declarations-variables)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:  No.
Consider a structure with multiple members of the same type:

```
struct Record
{
  int id;
  int age;
  float money;
  string name;
  string address;
};
```

The structure doesn't have a single integer, it has more than one integer and more than one string.

The member names help distinguish the fields in the structure.

Comment: yeah but  what I men if there are more of the same data type is to have more value under one variable what I mean is composite data types https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_data_type  I don't know if you understand me

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you.  A `struct` is a composite data type.  You can have many composite types in a composite type; they can be the same composite type or different.

Comment: Also, *types* cannot have values.  Variables, constants and literals can have a value.

Comment: so declaring the fields is just declaring a data types?

Comment: and the data types of the struct go to a variable right?

Comment: by that I mean declaring field make value for the variable ...?

Comment: I really suggest you read some books on data types and maybe take some algebra classes.  You are confusing variables and types.  The explanation is too long for StackOverflow.  Maybe search Wikipedia for "data type".

Comment: I read many things about oop and variables... some book say that a struct is just a variable with different data types others just say that is just a containers of variable I searched everywhere but that donesn't make a logic to me...