# Definition of a C++ variable, section Basic/6

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[basic] p6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#6) states:

> A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object. The variable's name, if any, denotes the reference or object.

```
int a = 0; // declaration of an object, this introduces the variable x, and an object is created
int{0}; // not a declaration of a variable, this does not introduce a variable, but an object is created
```

Does this mean that a variable IS an object or reference (that is not a non-static member)? Throughout the standard, they are referred to as if they have the properties of objects/reference, but the formal definition does not seem to state that. What confuses me is that the variables name refers to the object or reference, rather than the variable itself.

For example, here is what [[basic.life] p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-1.sentence-2) has to say:

> A variable is said to have vacuous initialization if it is default-initialized and [...]

This alludes to variables having the same properties as objects and references, as they can be initialized.

So my question is:

**Are variables simply a syntactic construct meant to group object and references that have been introduced by a declaration into one term? Is the variable itself the object or reference?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988716/what-is-the-definition-of-a-variable?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387412/can-any-one-explain-the-difference?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987259/why-is-a-non-static-data-member-reference-not-a-variable?rq=1 See this.

Comment: It seems to me that this definition of the word "*variable*" specifies how a variable is *introduced*, but it never gets around to specifying what a variable *is* (other than being a thing that has a name). It is, in my humble opinion, a poorly written definition.

Comment: Note that the quoted wording from [basic.life]/1 [was changed much recently](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/f3a6b2e671efdee5bacb74a5ea01d4bfb1900d3e).

Comment: @KeithThompson: It's a standard, not a reference manual. What "variable" means isn't consolidated in one place. This paragraph isn't meant to define the concept; it simply says what creates one.

Comment: @Krystian: It should be noted that the quote about vacuous initialization is probably a spec bug. C++17 speaks of *objects* having vacuous initialization; for example, `new int` uses vacuous initialization. Whereas this new wording only speaks of variables; `new int` cannot have vacuous initialization. Then again, I'm not sure what purpose "vacuous initialization" serves anymore, since they got rid of the exception that allows objects with vacuous initialization to come into being before their initialization is complete.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes, it's a standard. [intro.defs] says that terms in italics are definitions. The other definitions in [basic] either define the terms that are in italics or refer to terms that are defined by the syntax.

Answer (score 4):

As made clear in [Basic/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#3), variables are not "entities". Objects and references are entities, but not variables. As such, you could consider variables to be purely syntactic constructs rather than first-class C++ things.

Basic/6 tells us that a variable name [denotes](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/denote) the object/reference declared by that variable. This is supposed to be read as plain English: an object/reference created via a variable declaration has a variable name. And conversely, a variable names an object/reference created via a variable declaration.

So when the standard says:

> A variable is said to have vacuous initialization if it is default-initialized and...

It means:

> A [reference/object introduced by a variable declaration] is said to have vacuous initialization if it is default-initialized and...

Comment: So a variable is a object or reference that has been declared

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#7 seems to say that variables are in-fact entities. I believe that since variables are just a collective term for objects or references (that have been introduced through a declaration), they are entities transitively.

Comment: @KrystianS: "A local entity is a [reference/object introduced by a variable declaration] with automatic storage duration, a structured binding whose corresponding [reference/object introduced by a variable declaration] is such an entity, or the *this object."

Comment: Yes, so a variable is an entity transitively. Otherwise, "whose corresponding variable is such an entity" would not hold true.

Comment: @KrystianS: See my edited comment. It's the reference/object introduced by a variable declaration which is an entity, not the variable itself.

Comment: Yes, so variable is simply a encompassing terms for an object or reference introduced by a declaration. Otherwise, saying that a variable has the properties of an object or reference as is does throughout the standard would be incorrect.

Comment: Is the comment above correct? Since a variable declaration is a object/reference declaration, and since a variable names an object or reference, breaking it down should result in "a variable is an object or reference that has been declared", correct?

Comment: @KrystianS You asked last time the difference between "result" and "what an expression denotes". Here we have the same *figure of speech:* a [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy). The use of metonymies helps in having the standard shorter, but makes it less specific.

Comment: @Oliv so a variable is not an object, nor a reference, but it is used as if it is because it names an object/reference.